# Math.cos() gives wrong result

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

According to Wolfram Mathematica:
**cos(50)** = *0.6427876096865394*;

But this code in Java:

```
    System.out.println(Math.cos(50));
```

gives *0.9649660284921133*.

What is wrong with `java.lang.Math`?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

`Math.cos()` expects the parameter to be in radians. This will return the result you need:

```
Math.cos(Math.toRadians(50));
```

Comment: +1. Just for reference, as OP was talking about wolfram http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%2850rad%29

Comment: Is there a version of Math.cos() in Java that works with Degrees, or do we constantly need to remember to manually convert degrees to radians?

Answer (score 13):

[`Math.cos()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#cos%28double%29) uses *radians*, so to get your expected result you need to do

```
System.out.println(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(50)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Degrees <> radians...........

Comment: What this answer means ? Degree is equivalent to radian... but `1 degree = 0.0174532925 radians`

Comment: @Manu The `but` part in your comment is why they are not equivalent ;) It's like saying kilos and stone are equivalent. They measure the same quantity, sure, but in different ways.

Answer (score 2):

Most Java trigonometric functions expects parameters to be in radians. You can use Math.toRadians() to convert:

```
System.out.println(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(50)));
```

Answer (score -2):

For me...

```
System.out.println(Math.cos(50));
System.out.println(Math.cos(new Double(50)));
System.out.println(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(50)));
System.out.println(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(new Double(50))));
```

returns

0.9649660284921133
0.9649660284921133
0.6427876096865394
0.6427876096865394

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%2850deg%29

`cos(50deg)` give same result as `cos(50)`... so Wolfram is degree by default.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha does not use degrees by default! Rather, it is trying to be clever.

Comment: What is Wolfram Alpha default, degree or radian or ... ? Is there another base ? Can you give more argument about what you write ? Your comment does not give any information in fact ! My response does not respond to the initial question, so ok for "-1" flag but It give more information usefull about this conversation, I think.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha tries to guess whether your input is in radians or degrees: If the value is below 5, it seems to interpret it as radians, if it's larger or equal than 5, it interprets it as degrees ;) I have taken the liberty to correct the output that Java actually produces upon executing that code.

Comment: My `-1` was mainly due to this: `I don't know exactly what the meaning of these results but for me...`, apart from it not being a proper answer to the question. Given your code, you seem to try to guess what is happening, instead of having an understanding for it. This is further demonstrated by this: `Math.cos(Math.toDegrees(50))`  You feed a function that expects radians the value, that you get after converting 50 radians to degrees, a value that is completely random.

Comment: I'm agree with you... It is a mistake from me to feed by degree a method that expect radian. Like I said, I agree with people who give -1 AND give information about this : I expect it cannot be so easy to give -1. So thanks for explain, @phant0m. I will correct my answer so.

Comment: Do I have to aks an other question and make a relation between mine and this question if I try/want to understand why these method return different results ?

Comment: `new Double(50)` servers no purpose at all.